# Get text from br tags using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to extract the company name in the br tags from Indeed using python beautifulsoup.

HTML code:

`<p>
   <h2 class="jobTitle">
    <a href="viewjob?jk=1544ab41b4dc02b6" rel="nofollow">
     Data Scientist
    </a>
   </h2>
   <br/>
   Deloitte -
   <span class="location">
    Los Angeles, CA 90013
   </span>
   <br/>
   <span class="date">
    1 day ago
   </span>
  </p>`

I tried the following code but it comes out nothing.

```
companies=soup.find_all('br')
for company in companies:
   print(company.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain next_sibling

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.indeed.com/m/jobs?q=data+scientist&l=Los+Angeles%2C+CA')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
for job in soup.select('.jobTitle'):
    print(job.next_sibling.next_sibling)
```

Answer (score 0):

The company name isn't part of the `br` tag, instead, it is a raw text following the `br` tag.

Example:

```
prev = None
for child in soup.find('p').children: 
    if prev is not None and prev.name == 'br': 
        print(child) # company name
        break
    prev = child
```

Comment: any suggestions of how I can extract the company name

Comment: Updated my answer, does that help?

Comment: Here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/p3wUPekb. It works for me (output is "   Deloitte -".

Comment: I am not sure why the code doesn't work. This is the link I am trying to scrape from: indeed.com/m/jobs?q=data+scientist&l=Los+Angeles%2C+CA